# Web Audio - AudioParam scheduling functions not working

Tags: javascript, scheduling, web-audio-api

I think i am completely missing something. None of the `setValueAtTime(), linearRampToValueAtTime(), exponentialRampToValueAtTime(), setTargetAtTime()` methods of the AudioParam interface are working for me. The simplest possible example below:

```
var context = new window.AudioContext();
gain = context.createGain();
gain.connect(context.destination);

// none of this is working, gain stays at 1
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0.5, 0);
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0.2, 1);

setInterval(function () {
    console.log(gain.gain.value);
}, 100);
```

The expected is that the gain will be 0.5 and after 1 second it will be 0.2. However, it stays at 1. Same happens for every other scheduling method. Nothing works. What is the problem?

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/twxyz/qbo4tLfr/

EDIT: Obviously those methods are fine. I did the test with the audio source and the gain is changing audibly. Then my question is why console keeps logging initial value?

Comment: Perhaps try adding the current time to your 0 and 1 second marks? `audioCtx.currentTime `

Comment: I thought it was the issue but it isn't - nothing changes. I updated the fiddle for convenience though.

Comment: Should this be audible noticeable? Perhaps it happens before your timeout hits? Maybe try starting the timeout first. Or call `gain.connect...` last so the playback starts later.

Comment: The point isn't whether it should/shouldn't be audible. It is not working. I don't have the timeout, i'm simply checking the gain's value every 1/10 of a second...also why would it work only before connecting to the output...

Comment: What browser are you using ? For me it logs the gain perfectly fine(Chrome Stable - Linux)

Comment: @ LJ_1102 That is interesting. I've tried both latest (stable) Firefox and Chrome on Windows. Also, what do You mean by "fine"? Does it output something else than "1"?

Comment: @LJ_1102 Well, I should correct myself. It works fine with Chrome. So it seems that (sigh) the problem is with the Firefox, again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be an issue with the Firefox and had been reported as bug already: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=893020

Answer (score 1):

The automation values are not exposed in the .value attribute. See [computation of value](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#computation-of-value), bullet item 1.

Comment: Well, it says "When read, the `value` attribute always returns the intrinsic value for the current time" so...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intrinsic value is not the value that includes the automation stuff. It's the value that you set using the .value setter (or the default value for the attribute).

Comment: Look at my answer. .value getter _should_ return the intrinsic value at the time of calling according to the official specification and that this the case in Chrome. And a bug in Firefox.

Comment: No Raymond is right. Stricly speaking, Firefox respects the spec and Chrome does not. That said, I think the spec is wrong, and I should fix the spec and Firefox.